# How to make Leaflet Search actually search

Tags: javascript, search, leaflet

Implementing the Leaflet Search [example](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search#examples) just produces a search box. Nothing happens when you open it and start typing. The leaflet search code isn't being executed. It just shows the red `Location not found`. The graph shows area's of interest and I need to do something with the area's that match search criteria, to identify them to the user.

```
var searchLayer = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
//... adding data in searchLayer ...
map.addControl( new L.Control.Search({layer: searchLayer}) );
//searchLayer is a L.LayerGroup contains searched markers
```

There is code in the control to search to the data. It takes into account a geoJson data structure.

What am I missing in order to activate the search code?

Comment: Leaflet has no GIS web API. You need to use your own API or a 3rd party API like Google or Bing etc. Here's a project that might help you https://github.com/smeijer/leaflet-geosearch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although not explicitly explained in [Leaflet Control Search README](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search), the plugin will use the data in `marker.options.title` or in `feature.properties.title` by default.

You can specify a different key than `title` using the [`propertyName`](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search/blob/v2.7.2/src/leaflet-search.js#L79) option when instantiating the Search Control:

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([41.8990, 12.4977], 14);

var poiLayers = L.geoJSON(restaurant, {
  onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.amenity + '<br><b>' + feature.properties.name + '</b>');
  }
});

L.control.search({
    layer: poiLayers,
    initial: false,
    propertyName: 'name' // Specify which property is searched into.
  })
  .addTo(map);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
}).addTo(map);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-search@2.3.7/dist/leaflet-search.src.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-search@2.3.7/dist/leaflet-search.src.js"></script>

<script src="http://labs.easyblog.it/maps/leaflet-search/examples/data/restaurant.geojson.js"></script>

<div id="map" style="height: 200px"></div>
```